# Debian GUI Login after logged in via CLI (command line interface)?

Tags: linux, shell, automation, debian, command-line-interface

I have a Debian box, I have disabled the GUI with `sudo update-rc.d -f gdm3 remove`
It automatically logs into my desired user account. I then run a shell file that is to launch an X-Win program but it fails. At this point if I enable the GUI with `/etc/init.d/gdm3 start` then I am prompted by the Login screen.

What I need done is to run the shell script and have the program execute without the user doing anything and making it look like it boots to that program.

Q1: How do enable X-win after booting to a CLI.
Q2: executing my shell file at startup automatically

Answer (score 0):

You probably could use the [startx(1)](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/startx.1.html) (or [xinit(1)](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xinit.1.html) ...) command.

If your shell is `bash` you could put something in your `$HOME/.bashrc` (but I don't recommend doing that). Sometimes a login shell is not started by `getty` or `login` (e.g. it could be started thru `ssh` ....)